# Error while Launching activity : Error: Activity class { } does not exist

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un error con la ejecución de mi proyecto:

> Error while Launching activity

¿Alguien sabe como corregir este error?

En el link https://github.com/Austin52/App_Doc pueden encontrar el proyecto.

---

Este es el error que no puedo solucionar:

[image: ESTE ES EL EEROR QUE NO PUEDO SOLUCIONAR]

Encontré que tenia que deshabilitar pero aún así persiste el problema:

[image: ENCONTRE QUE TENIA QUE DESABILITAR PERO AUN ASI PERSISTE EL PROBLEMA]

Ya hice *clean project* y *make project*.

Comment: Austin, por favor agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml como texto esto ayudará a tener mejor información en el sitio, saludos

Comment: Podrias agregar cual es el mensaje de warning que te marca en el manifest? y tambien copiar el texto del mensaje de error completo?

Comment: Tambien me pasaba hasta que hice clic en buil->clean project y luego rebuild project, si aun asi no funciona prueva en file-> invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0):

Basándonos en tu error

> Error: Activity class {  com.example.austin.app_doc.Splash } does not
>   exist.

Es un poco raro ya que en realidad existe la clase en la ruta correcta:

```
  com.example.austin.app_doc.Splash
```

En este caso me parece que deberías forzar a construir nuevamente tu proyecto, mediante cualquiera de estas 2 opciones:

- `Build` > `Clean Project` => `Build` > `Rebuild Project`
- Eliminando los directorios `/build` (que son generados nuevamente al construir tu proyecto.

Si esto no funciona asegura que no tienes habilitada la opción "Instant Run":

Ve a `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Instant Run`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

** Update**
Estos pasos son suponiendo que no te faltan recursos

Es necesario resincronizar el proyecto con el gradle

- File > Sync Gradle with Project files
- Build > Clean project
- Build > Rebuild project

y problema resuelto.

Comment: No todos los errores se solucionan realizando esto. Si hay un problema en los recursos esto nunca funcionaría.

Comment: Tienes razón, esta solución es ya descartando si no hay problema con los recursos (referencias incorrectas, etc)